# Create shortcut to submit form

Tags: javascript, forms, scriptish

I work entering data online to a form and would like to assign a shortcut to each of two submit buttons.  I use Mac and Firefox.  Is there a way to do that in Scriptish, Applescript, or something other?

This is the source for one of them:

<<

Thanks

Comment: If you're developing the webpages, see [`accesskey`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_accesskey.asp). Otherwise, are you trying to modify the behavior for yourself as an enduser?

Comment: Yes, I am an enduser.  I have been using the stylish and scriptish add-ons to modify various aspects of the page for myself.  Don't know if there is a way to assign keys to jump directly to fields or submit forms.  I know a bit of javascript but no jquery.

Comment: This is the source:  <input type="submit" value="Save &amp; New" name="SubmitType" class="button">

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery Hotkeys

jQuery Hotkeys lets you watch for keyboard events anywhere in your code supporting almost any key combination.

To bind Ctrl+c to a function (f), for example:

$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+c', f);